# Why isn't the command "cmake ." generating a makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I run `cmake .` in terminal and it says it generated something, then I run `make` and it says

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I'm guessing I've missed something else that I need to do but I can't figure out what.  It should have created a make file that I can then build and then install.

If I'm being too vague please let me know what more I can add to this question.

*** edit ***

```
$ cmake .
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev):
  Policy CMP0042 is not set: MACOSX_RPATH is enabled by default.  Run               "cmake
 --help-policy CMP0042" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
 set the policy and suppress this warning.

  MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets:

  freeglut

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

 -- Generating done
 -- Build files have been written to:     /Users/nicholasl/Downloads/freeglut-3.0.0
```

**** contents of build directory ****

```
$ ls
AUTHORS             android
Build               android_toolchain.cmake
CMakeCache.txt          blackberry.toolchain.cmake
CMakeFiles          cmake_install.cmake
CMakeLists.txt          config.h
CMakeScripts            config.h.in
COPYING             doc
ChangeLog           freeglut.pc
README              freeglut.pc.in
README.android          freeglut.rc.in
README.blackberry       freeglut.xcodeproj
README.cmake            include
README.cygwin_mingw     mingw_cross_toolchain.cmake
README.mingw_cross      progs
README.win32            src
```

Comment: Generally you make a build directory, `cd` to it and then run `cmake ..`. Is that what is wrong?

Comment: @PaulRooney No, I've tried that also.

Comment: What is the output of cmake?

Comment: @DavidMarquant I don't know.  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Ehen you run cmake, what is printed in the console?

Comment: Can you show the output from cmake?

Comment: Output means no makefile was generated by cmake.
You have to check cmake configuration file.

Comment: I added the full output of what happens when I run "cmake ."

Comment: Looks like successfull `cmake` call. What is content of build directory after configuration? (Output of `ls /Users/nicholasl/Downloads/freeglut-3.0.0`).

Comment: I added the contents of the directory for you

Comment: ...Why did I get downvoted...

Comment: @NicholasL. no clue.   I'll help.

Comment: Close reason is no longer applied to the question. Voted for reopen.

Comment: The Build directory will have a makefile in it. You have given the output of `ls` on `/Users/nicholasl/Downloads/freeglut-3.0.0`.  Try `cd /Users/nicholasl/Downloads/freeglut-3.0.0/Build` and then run make.

Comment: Cmake generate makefiles of different type depending on what is available (and wich tool you chose).
On my Debian system, make exists but Cmake use Ninja by default.
So, like you I tried the command "make ..." and nothing happened but I realized that it uses Ninja ! So instead of using "make ..." I have to use "ninja ..." and it works.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems CMake defaults to generating an XCode project on Mac. CMake generated `freeglut.xcodeproj` along with all supporting files.

You are better off running `cmake` from an empty directory, so you can see what it actually does when it is run.

To generate a makefile (and create a build directory), do

```
mkdir -p cmake-build && cd cmake-build
cmake .. -G"Unix Makefiles"
```

Then it should generate a `Makefile`.

Comment: That did generate a makefile.  Thanks so much!  Now the makefile has an error when installing....  Ugh...

Comment: The cmake I use on os x doesn't default to generating xcode projects.  Looks like I'm using a homebrew installed version.

Comment: I think I remember messing with some settings in the actual cmake application (not through terminal).  Maybe I set it to output xcode without realizing what that meant.  I'm super lost.  Scenekit is so much easier but I want to work in C++...

Comment: @rubenvb Why you used the  `-p` while creating new directory?

Comment: @toRex adding `-p` also creates parent directories (only relevant when creating `some/subdirectory/with/multiple/levels`) but also does not fail if the directory already exists.

Comment: @rubenvb got it thanks!